# Uninstalling old version Django for upgrade to latest version

Tags: django, ubuntu

I want to upgrade Django from 1.2.5 to 1.3. I uninstalled 1.2.5 version, by the Ubuntu Software Center, for future upgrading, but it still in dist-packages and it still imported in python shell. What should I do? Would it be normal if I would brutally deleted the folder and egg from dist-packages?
It runs on Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend using setup-tools. Then run

```
easy_install --upgrade django
```

It will remove current django path from PYTHON_PATH and will add it's own path. To get easy_install do:

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
```

For both actions sudo is needed.

Comment: With the time, I can add - it's much better to use virualenv/virtualenvwrapper, it contains easy_install and pip. Both pip and easy_install support --upgrade. With this stuff your project will be encapsulated and you can have a several Django versions. http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/install.html

Answer (score 10):

Go to the `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`. Find `django` folder there and delete it. then [download django 1.3](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/) and run `python setup.py install`. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Remove django version using **pip**:

```
pip uninstall django
```

And install the version you want, for example 1.5:

```
pip install django==1.5
```